# Unidirectional ManyToMany join table not populated unless invoking refresh after persist commit

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying out some JPA+Hibernate configurations and I am facing an issue with a Unidirectional ManyToMany.
My test application is modeling a Person and an Event; the event has one creator, but many participants

Here is my Event:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EUO")
public class EventUnidirectionalRelationshipOwner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date eventDate;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner creator;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "participant_event_U")
    private Set<PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner> participants;

    protected EventUnidirectionalRelationshipOwner() {
        super();
    }

    public EventUnidirectionalRelationshipOwner(String title, Date eventDate,
            PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner creator) {
        this.title = title;
        this.eventDate = eventDate;
        this.creator = creator;
        this.participants = new HashSet<>();
    }

    /* get and set */

    public void registerParticipant(PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner participant) {
        participants.add(participant);
    }
}
```

The Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PUN", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "key_fNlNS", columnNames = {
        "firstName", "lastName", "ssn" }))
public class PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String ssn;

    /*
     * required by Hibernate. Protected because not meaningful for the
     * application (no default values for title and eventDate)
     */
    protected PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner() {
        super();
    }

    public PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner(String firstName,
            String lastName, String ssn) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }
    /* get and set */
}
```

Test main:

```
// CASE 1
PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner p1 = new PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner(
                "p1n", "p1l", "ssn1");
EventUnidirectionalRelationshipOwner e1 = new EventUnidirectionalRelationshipOwner(
                "e1", new Date(), p1);
PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner pp1 = new PersonUnidirectionalNonRelationshipOwner(
                "pp1n", "pp1l", "pssn1");
e1.registerParticipant(pp1);

EventDaoJPA.store(e1);
```

And finally the store method:

```
EntityManager em = DBResourcesManager.getEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(e);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

When I invoke store, however, the join table is not populated, while the entity tables are. 
In order to get the join table populated, I need to invoke em.refresh(e) after committing the transaction.
Is there a way to avoid this two-step-procedure?

Comment: No, that is correct. JPA 2.1 (as well as 2.0) spec says "The no-arg constructor must be public or protected."

Comment: OK, thanks for checking that. Indeed, for the entity class it must be either public or protected. For the EntityListeners it must be public (+ some other things).